# Is there a way to access a cloud function using peered VPC

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to connect to a cloud function with HTTP trigger. It has an ingress rule to allow only internal traffic, I want to access this from another function running in a different project.

I tried creating VPCs in both the projects and have also peered them. In the cloud functions I am using a vpc connector in the egress but I still am not able to access.

**Is there a direct way to access a cloud function running in say project-A from a cloud function running in say project-B using the network setting?**

P.S Due to some constraints I cannot use shared VPC.

Comment: AFAIK, Ingress rule is compliant with project VPC and VPC SC. I never tried with peered VPC, but, if it's not mentioned in the doc, it shouldn't work.

Comment: As per the docs [link](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/network-settings#ingress_settings), if you go to create function and select the advanced option you can get the ingress settings > Allow internal traffic only i.e; only traffic from the same project or traffic from the different project under same VPC Service Controls [link](https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/docs/overview) perimeter are allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't achieve this today. Indeed, when you perform a VPC Peering, you define a special hop in the routes to go to the other VPC.

The problem is: *When you call your Cloud Function, you don't call it by its IP but by its DNS.*

Thereby, you won't use your VPC peering to reach the right VPC and, through it, the cloud function. You will use the public DNS, as any external system can do this, and thus you are blocked.